# Value Error: Too many values to unpack

Tags: python

When I execute it, it is giving me an eror i.e too many values to unpack?
How do i make it to work properly.

```
  stack = util.Stack()
  closed = []
  child = []
  index = 0
  currNode = problem.getStartState()
  node = currNode
  stack.push(node)
  while not stack.isEmpty():
     node = stack.pop()
     if problem.isGoalState(node):
        print "true"
        closed.append(node)
     else:
         child = problem.getSuccessors(node)
         for nodes in child:
            stack.push(nodes)
         closed.append(node)
  return None
```

Error is:

```
 File  line 90, in depthFirstSearch
    child = problem.getSuccessors(node)
  File  line 179, in getSuccessors
    x,y = state
**ValueError: too many values to unpack**
```

The code for the getsuccessor func is:

```
def getSuccessors(self, state):
    """
    Returns successor states, the actions they require, and a cost of 1.

     """

    successors = []
    for action in [Directions.NORTH, Directions.SOUTH, Directions.EAST, Directions.WEST]:
      x,y = state
      dx, dy = Actions.directionToVector(action)
      nextx, nexty = int(x + dx), int(y + dy)
      if not self.walls[nextx][nexty]:
        nextState = (nextx, nexty)
        cost = self.costFn(nextState)
        successors.append( ( nextState, action, cost) )
```

The values returned for this function initially:

```
problem.getStartState() - (5, 5)
problem.isGoalState(problem.getStartState())- False
 problem.getSuccessors(problem.getStartState()) - [((5, 4), 'South', 1), ((4, 5), 'West', 1)]
```

Comment: if somebody needs more info, plz let me know.

Comment: @Shilpa: The error happens in line 179, so you should post the code there.

Comment: the 179 line is 
x,y = state

I have edited my question. Please see the getSuccessor function.

Comment: i can't modify this funct. I can change m,y code only which is given at the top the question.

Comment: What value is returned from `problem.getStartState()`?

Comment: (5,5) - this is the initial value

Comment: you can see the values returned by the function:- I have edited it and put the ans at the end of question.

Comment: Please stick to one question and edit that rather than continuously creating a new questions.

Answer (score 4):

First, it's unlikely that's the whole `getSuccessors` method, since there's no return value.

To guess, I'd say `getSuccessors` returns a list of tuples: (nextState, action, cost).  You're  storing each of those as nodes, which will fail when you pass one back into the method, and it tries to unpack the three values as two.

You owe it to yourself to find a decent debugger, and learn how to use it.  I use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) (with [PyDev](http://pydev.org/)), and it will significantly help you with these sorts of bugs.

Comment: I have edited the question. Now you can see the getsuccessor function. 179 line is x,y = state

Comment: moreover I cant change this code. I can change my own code which is at the top.

Comment: yes...u r absolutly right. But i cant think of changing my code. how do i make changes in my code.

Comment: try `for nodes, _, _ in child` rather than `for nodes in child`

Comment: I need to return the list of actions that reaches the goal. What value should I return then? I cant use return None after the while loop gets over.

Comment: I used ur method and when i execute it, it just gets stopped withour giving any result. That means the loop is completed and I need to return something at the end which is list of actions in the successor funct. What should I write then? return ?

Comment: You should probably go talk to whoever gave you this assignment, and tell them you really a refresher course on functions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why there is an inconsistent sized tuples being passed to `getSuccessors`, but you could probably fix it by checking the length of `node` after the `node = stack.pop()` line. If it's 3, then you'll want to pass `node[0]` in the line `child = problem.getSuccessors(node)`.

Comment: node is just a variable that stores the values of initail node which is (5,5). How do i check the length....print len(node)?

Comment: I need to return the list of actions that reaches the goal. What value should I return then? I cant use return None after the while loop gets over.